# Cannot find the base class when adding new class in MSVC 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using MSVC 2017 Community and am trying to add a new class with the wizard.

However, I'm receiving aforementioned error.

The problem is that the base class is defined in the library and the library is visible in the project.

Moreover, when I was using MSVC 2010 Pro I didn't have this issue. The wizard ran - it gave the warning but was able to complete successfully.

Is this the restriction of the Community Edition? Or something else is going on?

Comment: As a workaround, type the class manually in the source code without a wizard.

Comment: @Erlkoenig, that's just a workaround, if this is a restriction of Community Edition I will do that, but if its not - I'd prefer to have it available.

Comment: I think it sounds like a bug in VS. Or maybe there is a setting somewhere to have the wizard use the library.

Comment: @Erlkoenig, ok, for now I will type it in the code. hopefully someone will either confirm or deny my suspicion.